# How to subscribe to certain records in collection with id in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to meteor,I have two collections named Employee and Visitors.and two templates Home and Print. i can get the id of the record from the button like this.

```
printVisitor:function(){
    return Visitor.findOne({_id:Session.get('UpdateVisitorId')});
}
```

now when i click button that redirects to another page and i need to print those values say name, phone number using the particular id of record which i could get from the above code.
my route code looks like this

```
Router.route('/print/:_id', {
```

name: 'print',
  controller: 'PrintController',
  action: 'action',
  where: 'client'
});

and my print html is this

```
<template name="Print">

This is: {{VisitorName}}
Visiting:{{EmployeeName}}
Phone:{{PhoneNumber}}
```

how can i publish and subscribe and print those certain values of that id

Answer (score 1):

Publish and subscribe can take arguments. You also want to use `this.params` to get the URL parameters. This is the general pattern

```
Router.route('/foo/:_id', {

    name: 'foo',
    waitOn: function(){
      // this grabs the ID from the URL
      var someId = this.params._id;
      // this subscribes to myPublication while sending in the ID as a parameter to the publication function
      return [
        Meteor.subscribe('myPublication', someId)
      ]
    }

});


/server/publications.js

Meteor.publish('myPublication', function(id){
  check(id, String);
  return MyCollection.findOne({_id: id});
});
```

You'll now have access to the data you subscribed to on this route.

Comment: I've done what you said. now all i get is "loading....." in html. anything rong in my code?

Comment: @fuzzybabbybunny Hello mate, even I tried replicating this code but I'm seeing a similar error : All I can see is sacha's loading spinner work. Would be glad if you could check it out.

Comment: A loading screen means that the client is waiting for data from the server. If it doesn't stop loading, it means there's something wrong with the server sending data to the client - in this case, I forgot to put `check()` in the publish function. Meteor requires that all arguments sent to the server from a client be checked before they can be used. You should see an error pointing to this in your Meteor server console.

Comment: Spot on, mate! Works like a charm now. Thanks!

Comment: you need to change `return MyCollection.findOne({_id: id});` to `return MyCollection.find({_id: id});`, otherwise you will get `Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors` on the server side